# failed to authenticate user [elastic] after enabling xpack.security in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I Use Kibana 7.11.1 stack. this problem is related to elasticsearch alone.

I added `xpack.security.enabled: true` to elasticsearch.yml and ran `elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto`
to set the default users password. but now when I start elasticsearch I keep seeing the message:

```
[o.e.x.s.a.AuthenticationService] [SERVER_NAME] Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]
```

i see this only when elasticsearch service is up, so I assumed that I need to set the new `elastic` user password in `elasticsearch.yml` file, but i have no idea how..

any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: i would also like to know why elasticsearch is trying to authenticate to itself :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed one service that is part of the kibana stack. the elastic-agent.

so the database wasn't trying to connect to itself! :) elastic-agent was trying to connect to elasticsearch without the proper credentials.

once i resolved that and restart elastic-agent, the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**The error message indicates that the credentials with which you are trying to authenticate do not match the saved username and password.**

After turning on the `xpack.security.enabled` setting, you can set the [built-in user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html) credentials, using the below command

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

Comment: i already created the users while using the auto flag. why do i still get this error only from elasticsearch ?